# How can I get the last accessed date of the software

Tags: c#, asp.net, wmi

I wanna findout when did the software was last accessed? I tried to use `LastUse` property of Win32_SoftwareFeature. But it returns strange value (not date). Here's the code I used :

```
            string temp;
            string date;

            ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_SoftwareFeature");
            foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
            {
                if (mo["Name"] != null)
                {
                    temp = mo["Name"].ToString() +" Version " +mo["Version"].ToString();
                    lstTest.Items.Add(temp);


                    date = mo["LastUse"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Showing your code that demonstrates the issue (or at least values you are getting) would let people to answer... For WMI usually it easier to use VBS sample first (i.e. http://www.activexperts.com/admin/scripts/wmi/vbscript/0038/) to see what to expect from data.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the datetime using System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter. But even this breaks if the date time is 19800000*. Hence the code to parse date time will be.

```
        string dateString = mo.Properties["LastUse"].Value.ToString();

        if (dateString.Substring(4, 2) == "00" || dateString.Substring(6, 2) == "00")
        {
            d = DateTime.ParseExact("19800101", "yyyyMMdd", null);
        }
        else
        {
            d = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(dateString);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Date and time in WMI is represented in DMTF datetime format, so to convert to a .Net DateTime you must use the [`ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementdatetimeconverter.todatetime%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) Method.